# r ylab plot with utf-8

Tags: r, plot

in R, I try to make a plot with utf-8 in ylab

```
plot(x,y, ylab='Número')
```

but I get

[image: ss]

any suggestion?

Comment: Works for me with locale (`Sys.getlocale()`) set to `en_US.UTF-8` on Linux. Could you provide the OS, the locale and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when I make the plot in R, I don't have problem, the problem is when I imported a r script.

I imported the script with the `utf-8` encoding and fix the problem

```
 source('r_script.r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you contribution my friend.